# How to save and retrieve an image in a web application

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angular, express

I'm confronting a dilemma and I want to know what is the best practice in this case.
I am developing an application using Mysql for the database, ExpressJS, and Angular. I need to add the profile picture feature and I manage to upload the image and retrieve it from Angular to the Express App. My question is how should I save it to retrieve it everytimes I need it?
I know to save a file there are 2 solutions but none seems to work with me. the first one is to save the image in a folder directly in the disk and save the path to the database. But using this method, when later I need to retrieve the image and send back the path (.../backend/public/images/profilepictures) I have the error *not allowed to load local resource:...*
for the second method, saving the image directly the image into a BLOB column in the database. after doing so, the front-end just don't recognize the object as Blob but simply as object.
I have no more idea of what i should do for it to work.

so I tried to save the path and couldn't load the path saved in Angular because it is not saved in *.../frontend/assets/*
I tried to save the image in the database but what it is retrieved and sent is a object which is not comvertable back to BLOB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

u need to store images on CDN, which could be any (for example https://bunny.net/, you can find a better solution for you).
So you need to send an image to your server from FE, then store an image on CDN, and then store in the Database only URL from CDN for an image you uploaded.

This is an excellent practice that can increase delivery rate, because, usually, CDNs have cache and data centers in different counties, so your clients will download images faster than direct download from your server.
U can read more here https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/